# WAS Liberty Profile 8.5.5 set cache max age for fonts only

Tags: apache, caching, websphere-liberty, server.xml

Currently I am trying to solve the issue which is related with the fonts. They disapear once I hit refresh button. 
Browser: all IE versions.
 So I found the solution which is :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600"  
</IfModule> </FilesMatch>
```

However, the above solution is for Apache App Server. 
**Question: How can I achieve the same If am using WebSphere Application Server Version 8.5.5.5 Liberty Profile** ?

All possible configuration elements for server.xml : 
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/autodita/rwlp_metatype_core.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to write an extremely basic servlet filter that examines the request and adds the desired headers.  There is currently no configuration-only way to set response headers, much less conditional ones.

Answer (score 0):

If applicable, you can also just package the fonts with the app/resource that's trying to use them so you can use relative paths, but I understand that might not be desirable or possible in your situation.